# How the conditions are processed?

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

If the results is nil then I get `NoMethodError - undefined method 'length' for nil:NilClass:`

**Is there any way I don't have to use two conditions?** I thought that ruby won't evaluate the second part of the condition in case results is empty because the condition can be never true.

```
if (not results.empty? && results[-1].length == 2)
  (4-results[-1].length).times {|i| results[-1] << ""}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby the `not` operator has lower [precedence](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/language.html#table_18.4) than `&&` so your code is being interpreted as

```
not (results.empty? && (results[-1].length == 2))
```

You probably want to use the ! operator instead which does the same as `not` but has higher precedence.

Comment: Replacing `not` with `!` solved the issue. Thank you. Do you want to fix your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, they are deliberately different - I added the parens to show how ruby was interpreting your code, which was different to your intent

Comment: OK then ... what about `((not results.empty?) && results[-1].length == 2)` ? are `()` block expression in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider changing it to something that IMO "reads" better:

```
if results.any? && (results[-1].length == 2)
  ...
end
```

To avoid two explicit conditions, install the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/):

```
pry(main)> require 'andand'
pry(main)> r1 = []
pry(main)> r2 = ["hi", "there"]
pry(main)> r3 = ["hi", "no"]
pry(main)> puts "foo" if r1[-1].andand.length == 2
=> nil
pry(main)> puts "foo" if r2[-1].andand.length == 2
=> nil
pry(main)> puts "foo" if r3[-1].andand.length == 2
foo
=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you for the andand link. I am adding empty strings to the last element only if the length is == 2. I expect the length to be 4 but I read the values from csv file so it happened today that the length wasn't as expected. The file contains all results and each field has subfields separated by |, it happened that | was missing. So I add new empty elements after I do split('|') to make sorting happy. Sorting on one of the fields after split didn't work because the element was nil. Adding these empty elements solved it.

Comment: I cannot see `any?` method for array in http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html

Comment: Because it's not on `Array`, but [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F). It's better to search for method names rather than classes, because it's easy to guess wrong.